# HTML cell does not combine height when used multiple rowspans

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with basic structure as below. The problem is when I use same rowspan for all the columns the height collapses to one row only.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

when some of the columns have rowspans

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>1</td>
    <td rowspan=2>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When all the columns have rowspan. This is where the problem appears. Basically the expected result is for the first row to span two rows instead just one

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>1</td>
    <td rowspan=2>2</td>
    <td rowspan=2>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Table rows have no intrinsic height, they are just as high as their contents. If you make a table with nothing in the table cells, the rows will all be 0px high. (This is what happens in your last example with the empty second row.) So if you want to force a certain height, set this height explicitly in the stylesheet. `tr {height:1.5em;}` or something.

Comment: @MrLister the thing is. Im merging cells at run time so I can not predict what the height will be. I did gave them initial heights but it has same results. The only way I can see it is if I calculate the new height myself.

Comment: @MrLister I would really appreciate if you have any suggestion other than calculating the new cell height.

Comment: No, there won't be any other way. And do note, your cells with _rowspan_ still span those rows, though as Mr Lister stated, they will collapse to their content.

Comment: Thanks to both of you LGSon and MrLister

Comment: No suggestions, sorry. The empty tr has a height of 0, no matter if it partakes in rowspans belonging to another tr or not. It would have been nice if we could write something like `td[rowspan='2'] {height:200%;}` to make cells with a rowspan of 2 twice as high as the surrounding cells, but that doesn't work. You don't happen to know the exact height of the non-empty cells?

Comment: @MrLister In the current version, I do but in the next version I would not because I want to make it responsive. This issue also exist with colspan FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Lister mentioned, You might achieve that by styling td elements with rowspan. but instead of using percentage you should use em as unit.
`td[rowspan='2'] {height:2em;}`

That's the way table row height is calculated unless you specify height explicitly

Comment: Thanks Metti, I will try this later on. The thing is. I thought that I was doing something wrong or If there was something I was missing or did not know about. Apparently I have to handle the cell height myself. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the way table row height is calculated unless you specify height explicitly.

Comment: Im adding your answer as accepted answer since there is no better way. I also added your comment for other people if they have same issue